# How to translate from native sql to querydsl expression right?

Tags: java, sql, spring, left-join, querydsl

Given the following native SQL query:

```
@Query(
value =
"SELECT "
+ "jp.BLABSTATUSID BlabStatus, "
+ "s.BLABSTATUSBEZ BlabStatusBez, "
+ "COUNT(*) sumvalue "
+ "FROM JP jp "
+ " LEFT JOIN BLAB_STATUS s "
+ " ON jp.BLABSTATUSID = s.BLABSTATUSID "
+ "GROUP BY jp.BLABSTATUSID, s.BLABSTATUSBEZ",
nativeQuery = true)
```

that I use in my Java / spring context, I have to switch to querydsl.

I tried:

```
final QJpEntity e = jpEntity;
final QBlabStatusEntity f = blabStatusEntity;

    return jpaQueryFactory
        .from(e)
        .leftJoin(e.blabStatus, blabStatusEntity)
        .on(blabStatusEntity.blabstatusid)
        .groupBy(e.blabStatus.blabstatusid, f.blabstatusbez)
        .select(
            Projections.constructor(
                JPStatisticCounter.class,
                e.blabStatus,
                f.blabstatusbez,
                e.count()))
        .fetch();
```

but it cannot compile because it seems syntactically wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, it was a constructor type mismatch